Interesting NT Question With AP and GCD.
Find the number of prime triplets $(p, q,r)$ such that $p(p + 1), q(q + 1),r(r + 1)$ form a strictly increasing arithmetic progression, where GCD $(r − p, 2p + 1)=1$.
What I tried:
$r(r+1)-p(p+1)=2d$ where  $d$ is the common difference.
So $(r-p)(r+p+1)=2d=(r-p)[(r-p)+(2p+1)]$
I did some other stuff here and there though i am stuck.
Pls help thank you!!

Have you found any examples?

um can you explain @Sahaj why $p=q=r=-1/2$ is the only solution... tho its a great idea $2(q+\frac{1}{2})^2=(p+\frac{1}{2})^2 + (r+\frac{1}{2})^2$

You're right: there's multiple solutions (and I incorrectly labelled $\frac{-1}2$ as the only one).

@nonuser no its with 2p+1

With $p(p + 1)$, $q(q + 1)$ and $r(r + 1)$ forming a strictly increasing arithmetic progression, we have $p \lt q \lt r$, plus there are positive integers $a$ and $d$ where
$$p(p + 1) = a, \;\; q(q + 1) = a + d, \;\; r(r + 1) = a + 2d \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$
Adding RHS's of the first and third equation gives $2a + 2d = 2(a + d)$, i.e.,
$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
p^2 + p + r^2 + r & = 2q^2 + 2q \\
2p^2 + 2p + 2r^2 + 2r + 1 & = 4q^2 + 4q + 1 \\
(p^2 + 2pr + r^2 + 2p + 2r + 1) + (r^2 - 2pr + p^2) & = (2q + 1)^2 \\
(p + r + 1)^2 + (r - p)^2 & = (2q + 1)^2
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$
Using the Greatest Common Divisor Properties property that for any integer $c$ we have $\gcd(a + cb, b) = \gcd(a, b)$, then
$$\gcd(r - p, 2p + 1) = \gcd(r - p, (r - p) + (2p + 1)) = \gcd(r - p, p + r + 1) = 1 \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$
This shows \eqref{eq2A} forms a primitive Pythagorean triple. There are $2$ cases to check.

Case #$1$: $p = 2$
Since $r - p$ is odd, we then have for coprime positive integers $m$ and $n$ that
$$r - p = m^2 - n^2, \;\; p + r + 1 = 2mn, \;\; 2q + 1 = m^2 + n^2 \tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$
The second equation minus the first one gives
$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
2p + 1 & = -m^2 + 2mn + n^2 \\
2(2) + 1 + 2m^2 & = m^2 + 2mn + n^2 \\
5 + 2m^2 & = (m + n)^2
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$
This means that
$$2m^2 \equiv (m + n)^2 \pmod{5} \tag{6}\label{eq6A}$$
Since perfect squares are congruent to $0$, $1$ or $4$ modulo $5$, this shows that both $m$ and $m + n$ must be multiples of $5$. However, then from \eqref{eq5A} we get $25\mid 5$, plus both $m$ and $n$ are multiples of $5$, contradicting that $m$ and $n$ are coprime. Thus, there are no solutions for this case.

Case #$2$: $p \gt 2$
This means $r - p$ is even, so we have
$$p + r + 1 = m^2 - n^2, \;\; r - p = 2mn, \;\; 2q + 1 = m^2 + n^2 \tag{7}\label{eq7A}$$
Since $p \ge 3 \;\to\; q \gt 3$, then if $q \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$, we have $m^2 + n^2 \equiv 0 \pmod{3}$. However, since perfect squares are congruent to $0$ or $1$ modulo $3$, then $3$ divides both $m$ and $n$, contradicting that they are coprime. Thus, we have $q \equiv 2 \pmod{3} \;\to\; 2q + 1 \equiv 2 \pmod{3}$, so $m^2 \equiv n^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$. The first and second equations in \eqref{eq7A} then gives that
$$p + r + 1 \equiv 0 \pmod{3}, \;\; r \not\equiv p \pmod{3} \tag{8}\label{eq8A}$$
If $p \neq 3$, then $p \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$ and $r \equiv 2 \pmod{3}$, or vice versa, so $p + r + 1 \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$, contradicting the first equation in \eqref{eq8A}. Thus, this means that $p = 3$.
Similar to what we did for \eqref{eq5A}, the first equation minus the second one in \eqref{eq7A} results in
$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
2p + 1 & = m^2 - 2mn - n^2 \\
2(3) + 1 - 2m^2 & = - m^2 - 2mn - n^2 \\
7 - 2m^2 & = -(m + n)^2
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{9}\label{eq9A}$$
If $m$ were odd, then the LHS would be congruent to $5$ modulo $8$, so $(m + n)^2 \equiv 3 \pmod{8}$, which has no solution. Thus, $m$ must be even. However, adding the $3$ equations in \eqref{eq7A} gives
$$2r + 2q + 2 = 2m^2 + 2mn \;\;\to\;\; r + q + 1 = m(m + n) \tag{10}\label{eq10A}$$
Since $r$ and $q$ are both odd, the LHS is odd, so $m$ must be odd, contradicting that it needs to be even. Thus, there are no solutions for this case either.

Both cases having no solutions shows there are no prime triplets $(p, q, r)$ which satisfy the stated conditions.

Note: As indicated in Piquito's comment, a simpler and easier method is to note that, in both \eqref{eq4A} and \eqref{eq7A}, since $m$ and $n$ have different parities, we get
$$2q + 1 = m^2 + n^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{4} \;\;\to\;\; 2q \equiv 0 \pmod{4} \tag{11}\label{eq11A}$$
Thus, $q$ must be even, contradicting that $p \lt q$ with both being primes means $q$ must be odd.

thank you!!!!! will ask if i need some more clarification

this is a wonderfull solution i am in aww

@CLASHROYAL You're welcome. However, as I have explained in a note at the end, there's a simpler and easier method than what I used in my solution.

COMMENT.- We have $$p^2+p=q^2+q-d\\r^2+r=q^2+q+d$$ so $$p^2+p+r^2+r=2q^2+2q\iff(p+\frac12)^2+(r+\frac12)^2=2(q+\frac12)^2$$ then we have
$$(2p+1)^2+(2r+1)^2=2(2q+1)^2$$
The general solution of the diophantine equation $x^2+y^2=2z^2$ is given (like Phytagorean triplets) by the well known identity
$$(a^2-b^2+2ab)^2+(a^2-b^2-2ab)^2=2(a^2+b^2)^2$$ so we must have for primes $p,q,r$ the parameterization with integer variables $a,b$
$$p=\frac{a^2-b^2-2ab-1}{2}\\r=\frac{a^2-b^2+2ab-1}{2}\\q=\frac{a^2+b^2-1}{2}$$
This "smells" like impossibility, but I stop here because of the answer already given by John Omielan. If anyone wants to finish this different proof, do it.

FYI, although I'm not the downvoter, I suspect somebody might have done that because you don't have a complete solution, for even a part of the question. Also, regarding your statement "If anyone wants to finish this different proof, do it.", doing that by editing our answer would be quite inappropriate, although it may be acceptable if you make the answer community wiki. Alternatively, they could add their own answer extending yours, but I've ever only done that a few times and, as I recall, that was where the question had multiple parts, and I extended an answer that had at  least one ...

(cont.) part solved to extend it to solve at least one more part. Instead, I consider your approach to be interesting, and I'm willing to your answer an upvote if you clarify a couple of things and add at least an outline of how to finish it. Regarding the clarifications, I somewhat vaguely recall your formula, but it's like with primitive Pythagorean triples in that it's the general solution to coprime values (thus, $a$ and $b$ are coprime, with one being even and one being odd). Also, although I believe I can derive it myself (and you could likely as well), I suggest adding a reference ...

(cont.) to show that it's the general solution.  Next, you need to show the values are coprime, with this coming from noting that the $\gcd$ is odd and that $\gcd(2r+1,2p+1)=\gcd(2r+1-(2p+1),2p+1)=\gcd(2(r-p),2p+1)=\gcd(r-p,2p+1)=1$. Note that to finish the rest of it, you can basically use a similar approach to what I did.  First, if $p=2$, we have $5=a^2-b^2-2ab;\to; 5-2a^2=-(a+b)^2$ and then use modulo $5$. Next, with $p\ge 3$, then show that $q\neq 3$ means $a^2\equiv b^2\equiv 1\pmod{3}$. From $r-p=2ab$, we get $r\not\equiv p\pmod{3}$. ...

(cont.) From $p+r=a^2-b^2-1\equiv 2\pmod{3}$, if $p\neq 3$, then $p+r\equiv 0\pmod{3}$ instead, so $p=3$. We then get $7=a^2-b^2-2ab;\to;7-2a^2=-(a+b)^2$. Since $a$ can't be odd, it must be even. Add your equations for $r$ and $q$ gives $r+q=a^2+ab-1;\to;r+q+1=a(a+b)$. However, since $r$ and $q$ are odd, the LHS is odd, so $a$ must be odd too, contradicting it must be even.

@John Omielan.- I forgot to add the word COMMENT as I wanted to writte. Believe me, please, I didn't think you were the downvoter  (that wouldn't have been elegant given that you had given a good answer).

@John Omielan.- It is clear that $q\gt2$  and that $2q=a^2+b^2-1$ implies $a$ and $b$ have distinct parity. It follows $$2q=(2x)^2+(2y+1)^2-1\equiv0\pmod4$$ so $q$ should be even and cannot be odd prime. This finish the proof. Regards. Thanks you.

That's a lovely observation! This makes the rest of your solution considerably shorter and easier than what I suggested in my comments above. I, likewise, could have also used the same reasoning with my basically equivalent $2q + 1 = m^2 + n^2$ result to also make my answer shorter and simpler. I suggest you add this to your answer.

FYI, to help ensure your simpler and easier proof method than mine is more visible, I've added a note to the end of my answer, referencing your comment here.
